# React Native App Working in Development, 'Error: 'undefined' is not a function' in Production

Tags: react-native, testflight

I have completed an app that builds on both Android and iOS. It works as expected when I build the app from the CLI or when I build it via XCode / Android Studio. However, on TestFlight, it gets errors that simply do NOT exist when I build it locally. These errors only appear on TestFlight, and thus I have little to no idea on how to go finding them down or even resolving them. Does anyone have better expertise in this area?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how common an issue this is-- I've never heard of it before to be honest, but the components that were not working were components that utilized ({props}) in a component. For example, any component wthat utilized the following declarations did NOT work

```
function Example({props}){
   // stuff
}

// OR //

const Example = ({props}) => {
    // stuff
}
```

all of the values inside of props were unreadable. I fixed this by simply moving EVERYTHING into a recoil state instead and that mitigated any errors. For example...

```
navigation.navigate("path",{prop1: value}) 

// AND //

return (<Example prop={value} prop={value})
```

would not work unless the prop was a single value-- a string, an int, a bool, these would work. Objects and Arrays did NOT properly carry over.
Hope this helps someone in the future.